# How do you terminate the Python shell in Wing IDE?

Tags: python, shell, wing-ide

I'm fairly new to Python and have been using Wing IDE to play around with the features. One of the things that I could find while looking around was how to force terminate the Python shell when executing a command that won't terminate any time soon. An example would be:

```
import math
math.factorial(1000000)
```

I know in Visual Studio C++, the command is Ctrl+C, but what exactly is the Python equivalent?

Comment: that command is widely used. Executing your program on a unix shell for example, that command would work (I think so). If you are trying to do it in your IDE, just for seeing a screenshot I would say it's on the red stop sign

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method used to terminate execution varies between shells. For Wing IDE you use the **Restart Shell** item on the Options menu.

Comment: "Restart Shell" appears to completely wipe the state of the shell; in most interpreters, Ctrl+C-interruption leaves state intact as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on your shell. For most shells, it is ctrl-C, or killing the process.

There is no way to do so from within python (unless you are spawning threads or processes) because the thread in question is stuck.